# IOS - Set an Image as Form Layout, and X/Y coordinates of Click on an Image

Tags: ios, image, background, click, coordinates

I am having a problem with my IOS app. In my app, I want my home page so-to-speak to be all one large image which people will click to get into various other screens. How do I set it so the image takes up the entire screen, and how do I find out the X/Y coordinates of where someone clicked?

Answer (score 0):

For the image, you can use UIImageView class and set or initialize it to the size of your home screen.
For tap (click), you can use UITapGestureRecognizer class (see the link below)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html